VB.Net Context Menu items click not firing in the web browser
I'm working on the context menu items to get the messagebox to display when I click on the context menu items. The click event for the context menu items will not be firing when I create custom right mouse click event for the web browser.
I have tried a few number of ways to get it to work and none of them will works, it keep going around the circle as nothing will happens when I click on the context menu items.
Here is what I have tried:
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script></head><body><div id='main' class='main' style='padding-left: 13px;'><div id='editor' dir='auto' placeholder='' aria-multiline='true' contenteditable='true' tabindex='1'></div></div></body></html>"

    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = html
    WebBrowser1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1
End Sub

Private Sub MenuItem4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handler MenuItem4_Click
    MessageBox.Show("Copy")
End Sub

And I have also tried this:
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim html As String = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js'></script></head><body><div id='main' class='main' style='padding-left: 13px;'><div id='editor' dir='auto' placeholder='' aria-multiline='true' contenteditable='true' tabindex='1'></div></div></body></html>"

    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = html
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

    AddHandler WebBrowser1.Document.MouseDown, New HtmlElementEventHandler(AddressOf WebBrowser1_MouseDown)
End Sub



Private Sub WebBrowser1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As HtmlElementEventArgs)

    If e.MouseButtonsPressed = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        ContextMenu1.Show(WebBrowser1, New System.Drawing.Point(e.MousePosition.X, e.MousePosition.Y))
        AddHandler MenuItem4.Click, New EventHandler(AddressOf MenuItem4_Click)
    End If
End Sub


Private Sub MenuItem4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Copy")
End Sub

Do you know why the context menu items will not be firing when I click on the context menu items?
If I did something wrong, can you please show me an example what is the correct way to get the context menu items to firing when I click on the items after I click on the right mouse button on the web browser?

To show your own ContextMenu, you have to set IsWebBrowserContextMenu = false, otherwise the native one is presented. You can assign your ContextMenuStrip in the Designer -- Don't use the code in the second snippet, not good

I have already set the property IsWebBrowserContextMenu to false but the context menu still wont trigger so I dont know why. I want to use normal context menu without the contextmenustrip. And I want to use the code in the second snippet because I am working on the webbrowser for writing an email. However, I have manage to get the context menu to work without the web browser, e.g: ContextMenu1.Show(Me, New System.Drawing.Point(PosX, PosY)) instead of this ContextMenu1.Show(WebBrowser1, New System.Drawing.Point(PosX, PosY))

Am I using the correct code to display the context menu in the web browser by using this ContextMenu1.Show(Me, New System.Drawing.Point(PosX, PosY))?

IF you MUST use a ContextMenu (which I suggest you ditch, since it's no longer available in .NET 5+), then you just need contextMenu1.Show(WebBrowser1, e.MousePosition) -- You must not add a new event handler to the MenuItem4.Click on each MouseDown event, these event handlers accumulate. Add just one when you create the MenuItem. But, why are doing this, when you can simply set WebBrowser1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1 as you're doing in the first snippet? You don't need anything else. These are the main reasons why a wrote Don't use the code in the second snippet, not good

@Jimi Thank you for your advise, I can see that it is working great when I am using contextMenu1.Show(WebBrowser1, e.MousePosition). Do I have to use contextMenu1.Show(WebBrowser1, e.MousePosition) in the mouse_down event? if not could you please post an example code with what I could use in a proper way?

As previously mentioned, you don't need that: when you have set this: WebBrowser1.ContextMenu = contextMenu1 and (my first comment) IsWebBrowserContextMenu = false, the WebBrowser Control shows your Menu where you right-click it. Nothing else to do

In the first code, the context menu item didn't trigger because you didn't set the property IsWebBrowerContextMenuEnabled in WebBrowser1 to false.

I have tested the second code and found it feasible. Can you provide more information about your projects and operations? So that I can help you solve it.

Thank you very much for this, I have already set the property IsWebBrowerContextMenuEnabled in WebBrowser1 to false and the context menu item still didn't trigger. From what I can see you are using ContextMenuStrip which I am not using it, I am using normal context menu.

In more modern Windows Forms applications, ContextMenuStrip provides better event handling and interaction, especially with newer controls like WebBrowser. Consider replacing the older ContextMenu with ContextMenuStrip.See the link below for details(https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.contextmenu?view=netframework-4.8.1#definition).
